# Chartjs change grid line color

Tags: chart.js

First I don't know what's it called. But how do you change its color from gray to white? Or is it even possibe?

[image]

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It is possible to either remove the grid lines or have them display in a different color.

In both `options.scales.xAxes` and `options.scales.yAxes` you can add

```
gridLines: {
  display: false ,
  color: "#FFFFFF"
},
```

(obviously you do not need to assign a colour if you are not disaplying them)

```js
var chartColors = {
  red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
  yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
  green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
  blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
  purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
  grey: 'rgb(231,233,237)'
};

var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1.0 : -1.0) * Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
}
var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      backgroundColor: chartColors.red,
      borderColor: chartColors.red,
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor()
      ],
      fill: false,
    }, {
      label: "My Second dataset",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: chartColors.blue,
      borderColor: chartColors.blue,
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor()
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label',
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Month'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Value'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: how to apply grid line color to specific line having the lowest value on (y-axis) ?

Comment: can we set thickness to specific horizontal grid lines?

Comment: @AsifIqbal Do you able to find the way to color specific grid line ?

Comment: @ARJUN and for the others looking to change the lowest line (first line Y axis), it's the `zeroLineColor` property. E.g.
`gridLines: {color: "#FFFFFF", zeroLineColor: "#FFFFFF" }`

Answer (score 20):

Since v3 the scales have been changed so if you want your gridlines to have a different color you will need to configure it in `options.scales[scaleID].grid.color`:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        grid: {
          color: 'white'
        }
      },
      x: {
        grid: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      display: true,
      grid: {
        display: false
      },
    },
    y: {
      display: true,
      grid: {
        display: false
      },
    }
  }
}
```