# Change the Labels of yAxis in chartJs

Tags: javascript, charts

Trying to get a linechart in ChartJS. I want the yAxis Labels should be 0, 250k, 500k, 750k only.

How can I change the labels so it will always have 0 as a minimum?

```
var lineChartData = {
  labels: ["Jun 1", "Jun 2", "jun 3", "Jun 4", "jun 5", "Jun 6", "Jun 7", "Jun 8", "Jun 9", "Jun 
         10", "Jun 11", "Jun 12", "Jun 13", "Jun 14", "Jun 15"],
  datasets: [{
               fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
               strokeColor: "rgba(220,180,0,1)",
               pointColor: "#ffc000",
               data: [190, 200, 420, 390, 150, 250, 160, 155, 200, 260, 240, 500, 300, 210, 230, 270]
             },
             {
               fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0)",
               strokeColor: "#ff1e6d",
               pointColor: "#ff1e6d",
               data: [290, 390, 300, 440, 625, 375, 390, 325, 280, 295, 385, 295, 485, 280, 265]
             }]
   }

   Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 50;
   Chart.defaults.global.tooltipYPadding = 16;
   Chart.defaults.global.tooltipCornerRadius = 0;
   Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTitleFontStyle = "normal";
   Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFillColor = "rgba(0,160,0,0.8)";
   Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = "easeOutBounce";
   Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
   Chart.defaults.global.scaleLineColor = "#816cab";
   Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontSize = 16;
   Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontColor = "white";

   var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
   var LineChartDemo = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
         pointDotRadius: 10,
         bezierCurve: false,
         scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
         scaleGridLineColor: "#816cab"
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Like this:

```js
var lineChartData = {
  labels: ["FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER", "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "X",
    fillColor: "#ff1e6d",
    strokeColor: "#ff1e6d",
    pointColor: "#ff1e6d",
    data: [290, 390, 300, 440, 625, 375, 390, 325, 280, 295, 385, 295, 485, 280, 265]
  }, {
    label: "Y",
    fillColor: "#ffc000",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,180,0,1)",
    pointColor: "#ffc000",
    data: [190, 200, 420, 390, 150, 250, 160, 155, 200, 260, 240, 500, 300, 210, 230, 270]
  }]
}

Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 50;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipYPadding = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipCornerRadius = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTitleFontStyle = "normal";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFillColor = "rgba(0,160,0,0.8)";
Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = "easeOutBounce";
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleLineColor = "#816cab";
Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontSize = 11;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontColor = "white";

new Chart(document.getElementById("fill"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: lineChartData,
  options: {  
    pointDotRadius: 0,
    bezierCurve: true,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    scaleGridLineColor: "transparent",
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            min:0,
            max:1000,
            stepSize: 250
        }
     }]
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="fill"></canvas>
```

Comment: yes now it works very fine. Thank you so much my brother. Dear sir.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094658/chartjs-change-grid-line-color

Comment: One thing more sir in which you can help.
Following things are not working:
pointDotRadius: 10,
bezierCurve: false,
 As well as to change grid line colors and remove legends, change the data line colors. labels font color.
These things should work.

Comment: Actually Sir I can't understand how to fix and place it in that above code