# How to change chart.js grid, and axis color?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chart.js and jQuery, my chart look like this on light mode.

[image]

Lately, I added a .dark class to my body

```
body{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;

}

body.dark {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

[image]

I can't see the x,y axis line or grid. How can I change the color of that to white ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chartjs change grid line color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094658/chartjs-change-grid-line-color)

Comment: https://codepen.io/cypherjac/pen/mdqGrvd - Chartjs grid axes color ... You can experiment here, same as @Yash's answer

Answer (score 1):

In chart.js there is a configuration for cartesian axes, as per the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/)
. You can change the config like this to handle the colour of the X and Y axes.

```
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          borderColor: 'white'
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          borderColor: 'white'
        }
      },
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is correct ? It is not working for me;

Comment: @code-8 I think you are using `timeseries` axes. There is something called [scaleId](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/), by default it is `x` and `y`. Please check if you have changed them. Please check this for [timeseries axes styles](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html)